# Task Scheduler with .dll

Tags: c#, dll, .net-core, console-application, taskscheduler

net core 2.0 console app on a schedule only problem is i have a .dll file - I have followed resources which say to put the 'Start-in' option to the path of project and this hasn't worked - however when I navigate to the folder with the dll and run dotnet name.dll in cmd it executes the console app fine.

Here is the error i'm getting

```
   Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Try adding a direct package reference to System.Runtime 4.3.0 and see if that changes anything

Answer (score 0):

rsine provided the answer in his question [Scheduling multiple .net core console apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44849115/scheduling-multiple-net-core-console-apps).

Example of 'New Action' form

Program/Script dotnet

Add Arguments program.dll arg1

Start In E:\User\ProgramFolder

[image: picture]